# Using ffmpeg -sseof with pipe

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I am working on extracting and transcoding a clip from a 4K video.
I already know where to start and how long the clip should last.

I am using the following command to extract the clip I need (30 sec into the video, I take a 10 sec clip)
`ffmpeg -ss 30 -i 'input.mp4' -c copy -t 10 -f matroska 'output.mp4'`

In order for the video to retain the key frame, so it knows what to draw, the clip can be longer than 10 sec (which is to be expected)

I can then use the following to transcode the video, and make sure it only takes the last 10 seconds (Specifically the `sseof` command)
`ffmpeg -sseof -10 -i 'output.mp4' -vcodec libx264 -r 15 -s 720x400 -aspect 720:400 -sn -f matroska -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 11025 -y 'transcoded.mkv'`

Due to a slow file system, I would like to avoid the first step of writing the extracted clip to the disk, I can do this with pipes and just transcode on the fly.
`ffmpeg -ss 30 -i 'input.mp4' -c copy -t 10 -f matroska pipe:1 | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -vcodec libx264 -r 15 -s 720x400 -aspect 720:400 -sn -f matroska -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 11025 -y 'transcoded.mkv'`

However with pipes I can not use the `-sseof` command, as it just makes an invalid video clip file. (There are no errors or warnings from the log)

My current solution is to transcode the transcoded video clip again, and only take the last 10 seconds. (But this seems like a poor workaround, and not a real solution)

As this is my first time working with `ffmpeg`, I am wondering if it is possible to take the last 10 seconds of a video through a pipe? Or maybe somebody has an even better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but all you need is

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i 'input.mp4' -t 10 -vcodec libx264 -r 15 -s 720x400 -aspect 720:400
       -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 11025 -sn -f matroska -y 'transcoded.mkv'
```

Comment: For some reason, if the input file is a `.mkv` or `.ts` file, it will actually transcode the first 30 seconds, even though it is set to skip them. (Or at least that is what it looks like if I inspect the CPU and see its load) However if the file is a `.mp4` it works as expected. Unfortunately I must be able to handle all 3 file types.

Comment: Works here as expected with TS and MKV.

Comment: If I use this file as input [4ksamples](http://4ksamples.com/elysium-2013-2160p-1-minute-sample-footage/), setting `-ss 0` takes roughly 8 sec, whereas `-ss 45` takes roughly 14 sec (on my machine that is). This is a pretty huge increase for skipping 45 sec. Am I misunderstanding something, or is it suppose to work like this?

Comment: Must be your system. Takes 10.73s for the whole execution with `-ss 45` for that sample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to be working on other machines.